# What is the correct value to use for the `default` option in tkinter.messagebox`?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I cannot get the `default` option of `tkinter.messagebox` to work. May I know what is the correct value to use for the `default` option?

Sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

root = tk.Tk()

def confirmExit():
    # mbox = messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Shut down?", icon="question",
    #                               default="yes")  # don't work
    mbox = messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Shut down?", icon="question",
                                  default=tk.YES)  # don't work
    if mbox:
        root.destroy()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', confirmExit)
root.mainloop()
```

Error msg 1:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/messagebox.py", line 76, in _show
    res = Message(**options).show()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/commondialog.py", line 45, in show
    s = master.tk.call(self.command, *master._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad -default value "yes": must be abort, retry, ignore, ok, cancel, no, or yes
```

Error msg 2:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/messagebox.py", line 76, in _show
    res = Message(**options).show()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/commondialog.py", line 45, in show
    s = master.tk.call(self.command, *master._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad -default value "1": must be abort, retry, ignore, ok, cancel, no, or yes
```

Comment: You are using *`askokcancel`*, so the `default` option should be `ok` or `cancel`.

Comment: It's telling you the valid options right in the error message!  Try `"ok"`, for example.  (You get a different error message if you choose an option that doesn't correspond to an actual button being displayed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the `askokcancel` variant, the possible values for `default` are `"ok"` and `"cancel"`.

```
mbox = messagebox.askokcancel(..., default="ok")
```

The valid values depend on the type of the dialog. From the official tk documentation, the values for each dialog type are:

| dialog type | valid values for `default` |
| --- | --- |
| abortretryignore | "abort", "retry", "ignore" |
| ok | "ok" |
| okcancel | "ok", "cancel" |
| retrycancel | "retry", "cancel" |
| yesno | "yes", "no" |
| yesnocancel | "yes", "no", "cancel" |